# Cannot be converted implicitly form NotFoundResult in List in an API

Tags: api, asp.net-core, controller, implicit-conversion

I had an API, but I need to return now several records, so, I had to add ToListAsync(), and now the error comes out in the NoFound line:
Cannot be converted implicitly form NotFoundResult in List

I know that I have to change the return type, but I don't know which I can use.

```
// GET: api/GetServicio/5        
[HttpGet("GetServicio/{tecnico}/{semanaDelAno}")]
public async Task<List<Servicio>> GetServicio(string tecnico, int semanaDelAno)
{
            var servicio = await _context.Servicio.Where(i => i.Tecnico == tecnico && i.SemanaDelAno == 
            semanaDelAno).ToListAsync();

            if (servicio == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return servicio;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code like below.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetServicio(string tecnico, int semanaDelAno)
    {
        var servicio = await _context.Servicios.Where(i => i.Tecnico == tecnico && i.SemanaDelAno ==
        semanaDelAno).ToListAsync();

        if (servicio.Count == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(servicio);
    }
```

Comment: With this above: [HttpGet("GetServicio/{tecnico}/{semanaDelAno}")]   it works, thanks @Yinqiu